# Get manifest info of remote jars

Tags: java, ant, jar, versioning

I have to manage a situation where I have multiple jars released on various server environments without a proper release policy.

This means, I can't know which version has been released on a given server unless I explicitly check.

I'm pushing to have such a policy put in place, but until then I'm in the dark.

Anyway, I managed to insert in the build script the valorization of some basic information (timestamp, user who run the build), so I have some basic data to bring the situation under control.

What I want to do is read that information, and create a report telling me the overall situation.

I can certainly write a script myself in two ways:
- download jars from each server and extract manifest info;
- run a remote utility which extract the manifest and returns info.

Is there some tool/script/ant-task able to accomplish this task, or should I write one myself?

Comment: I am not aware of any existing solution in ant.

Answer (score 1):

You somehow need to get inside each jar. If you know their location suppose they are deployed all under one location (or a root folder) you can have a script that will use some combination of **jar, grep** and **find** probably.

```
for i in *.jar; do jar -tvf ....
```

I can't really think of another way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I found part of the answer here:

[Ant Task to read directly from a JAR Manifest file](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ant-user/200812.mbox/%3C9EE86F1965E19E499C80DE52AC807B5502A477D1@z011021.bk.fin.local%3E)

```
<project>

    <!-- Get a jar -->
    <copy file="${ant.home}/lib/ant.jar" todir="."/>

    <!--
    Loads entries from a manifest file.
    @jar     The jar from where to read
    @prefix  A prefix to prepend
    -->
    <macrodef name="loadmf">
        <attribute name="jar"/>
        <attribute name="prefix" default=""/>
        <sequential>
            <loadproperties>
                <!-- Load the manifest entries -->
                <zipentry zipfile="@{jar}" name="META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"/>
                <!-- Add the prefix -->
                <filterchain>
                    <prefixlines prefix="@{prefix}"/>
                </filterchain>
            </loadproperties>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>

    <!-- Read mf entries -->
    <loadmf jar="ant.jar" prefix="ant-mf."/>
    <!-- Print them -->
    <echoproperties prefix="ant-mf."/>

</project>
```

It pretty much does what it says.

Output is something like:

```
Buildfile: C:\dev\ant\build.xml
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\dev\ant
[echoproperties] #Ant properties
[echoproperties] #Wed Jan 25 12:02:09 CET 2012
[echoproperties] ant-mf.=
[echoproperties] ant-mf.Ant-Version=Apache Ant 1.8.1
[echoproperties] ant-mf.Created-By=1.5.0_22-b03 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
[echoproperties] ant-mf.Extension-name=org.apache.tools.ant
[echoproperties] ant-mf.Implementation-Title=org.apache.tools.ant
[echoproperties] ant-mf.Implementation-Vendor=Apache Software Foundation
[echoproperties] ant-mf.Implementation-Version=1.8.1
[echoproperties] ant-mf.Main-Class=org.apache.tools.ant.Main
[echoproperties] ant-mf.Manifest-Version=1.0
[echoproperties] ant-mf.Name=org/apache/tools/ant/
[echoproperties] ant-mf.Specification-Title=Apache Ant
[echoproperties] ant-mf.Specification-Vendor=Apache Software Foundation
[echoproperties] ant-mf.Specification-Version=1.8.1

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 2 seconds
```

This is the basic stuff I need to get my task done.